# rav4 2L diesel, 2002, engine failure

Tags: toyota, diesel, rav4, engine-swap

engine gone in my 2002 rav 4, 2L, diesel, but can i replace it with an avensis, corolla 2L diesel or other toyota?
obviously keeping my original turbo, starter etc.

mark

Answer (score 0):

The diesel engine in the XA20 RAV4 is the 1CD-FTV (marketed as "2.0 D-4D") - the same basic block was used in the E120 Corolla (exact model years depend on your location - it started in Japan in 2000 but came later to some markets IIRC) and both are built on the same basic platform - Toyota's "MC" platform so that makes it reasonably likely that you can do such a swap.

The Avensis used the 1CD-FTV as well (until '09) in some of the cars - however some of the  second generation Avensis cars had the 1AD-FTV instead. So it would be advisable to check carefully! I *think* they started using that ~2005 so cars before that should be the right engine.

2nd generation (03-09) Avensis cars are also built on the MC platform.

I must stress that this isn't a swap I've seen done personally so I don't know for *sure* that it's doable - would have to check part numbers for that and without the frame numbers of the recipient and donor that's a needle in a stack of needles.

Comment: You'll want to pay attention to the motors' fuel injection systems as well; it's possible that the system installed on the original now-dead motor is different from the system installed on the donor motor.

Comment: @David If the donor is a 1CD-FTV engine then they should all be the same injection -wise. That engine only came in a common rail setup. I'd be surprised to see any meaningful difference between installations in different targets but never say never I guess!

Comment: I'm with you. It'd be excellent if the systems were the same, but one should remain conscious that they may be different. Swap on!

Comment: @David agreed.. it always pays to check first with this sort of thing!